# Nested FOR loop in AMPScript after reading from XML

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

For example if there are nested entities in an XML string I would need to loop over the parent entities and the child entities (like a repeater within a repeater in ASP.NET). If you would like an example of such XML I can paste it here.

As requested, an example snippet of what I am trying to achieve:

```
%%[ Var @xml, @names, @talents, @talent, @rows

Set @xml = '
<root>
    <parent-object>
        <name>Dan</name>
        <surname>Surname</surname>
        <talents>//child object to obtain which would be acquired through nested for loop
            <talent-name>fast worker</talent-name>
            <experience>2 years</experience>
            <talent-name>typing</talent-name>
            <experience>3 years</experience>
        </talents>

    </parent-object>

    <parent-object>
        <name>John</name>
        <surname>Surname</surname>
        <talents> //child object to obtain which would be acquired through nested for loop
            <talent-name>runqning</talent-name>
            <experience>2 years</experience>
            <talent-name>walking</talent-name>
            <experience>3 years</experience>
        </talents>
    </parent-object>

</root>'




Set @names = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//root/parent-object/name",1)

Set @talents = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//root/parent-object/talents/talent-name",1)



SET @rows = RowCount(@names)
for @cnt = 1 to @rows do //start loop

Set @name = Field(Row(@names,@cnt), "Value")
Set @talent = Field(Row(@talents,@cnt), "Value")



]%%


 <div>  
  - %%=v(@name)=%% <br>


 Talents: %%=v(@talent)=%% <!-- //displays single talent. Here is where i would require an inner for loop to iterate over talents. I would like to do this without separating the xml -->
 </div>





%%[next @cnt]%%
```

Comment: Please update your question with some of your work-in-progress code along with an XML sample.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs, please see updated question

Comment: I think [my answer](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/93622/5202) to this other question is appropriate here.

Comment: As for the nested `talents` node, you can always build another rowset inside your `for` loop.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs, How would i build the rowset so that it relates to the current iteration of the for loop?

Comment: @AdamSpriggs I can't see how that answer you linked me to or your comments here can help me. You seem to know enough to write an answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For iterating through the child elements, you'll need to utilize the XPATH index to limit the scope of the BuildRowSetFromXML() results (as in the example I cited in my comment).  See the `Set @talents =` line below:

```
%%[

Var @xml, @i, @j, @names, @talents, @talent, @rowCount1, @rowCount2

Set @xml = "
<root>
    <parent-object>
        <name>Dan</name>
        <surname>Surname</surname>
        <talents>
            <talent-name>fast worker</talent-name>
            <experience>2 years</experience>
            <talent-name>typing</talent-name>
            <experience>3 years</experience>
        </talents>
    </parent-object>
    <parent-object>
        <name>John</name>
        <surname>Surname</surname>
        <talents>
            <talent-name>runqning</talent-name>
            <experience>2 years</experience>
            <talent-name>walking</talent-name>
            <experience>3 years</experience>
        </talents>
    </parent-object>
</root>"

set @names = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//root/parent-object/name",1)
set @rowCount1 = RowCount(@names)
outputline(concat("<br>rowCount1: ",@rowCount1))
for @i = 1 to @rowCount1 do

    Set @name = Field(Row(@names,@i), "Value")
    outputline(concat("<br><br>name: ",@name))

    Set @talents = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat("//root/parent-object[",@i,"]/talents/talent-name"),1)

    set @rowCount2 = rowCount(@talents)
    outputline(concat("<br>rowCount2: ",@rowCount2))

    for @j = 1 to @rowCount2 do
         Set @talent = Field(Row(@talents,@j), "Value")
         outputline(concat("<br>&nbsp;talent: ",@talent))
    next @j

next @i
]%%
```

**Output**

```
rowCount1: 2 

name: Dan 
rowCount2: 2 
 talent: fast worker 
 talent: typing 

name: John 
rowCount2: 2 
 talent: runqning 
 talent: walking
```